# Why won't Ubuntu let me create a user account named "games"?

Tags: users

I downloaded the source for "nethack", and it suggests I create a user and group named "games".  But when I click on (gear symbol) -> System settings -> User accounts from the menu bar, Ubuntu will not allow me to create a user account named "games".  When I type that name in, the "Create" button grays out.  Yet the same window clearly shows me that my name is the only user account that already exists on the machine.  What is the problem and how do I get around it?

Comment: is it grayed no matter what name you use to try to create a new user... like if you tried to create a user called "Joe" is the button still grayed? If so .. there is probably somewhere to "Unlock" or "Change settings" .. which will ask for the sudo password because adding a user needs to be done from sudo/root. Not sure what version of Ubuntu you are using but in Unity Desktop 16.04 there is an Unlock button in the upper right corner you have to click on before you can change anything

Comment: I would bet you one actual nickel that if you run the command `grep games /etc/passwd` it will indeed show that there is a disabled account called `games` already on the system, but I don't want to take your money.

Answer (score 6):

Games is a standard system userid on Debian-based systems.  There are many of these with UIDs < 1000.  This allows the system to setup services with minimal privileges.  This follows the least privilege model.